# Проблема c кодировкой MySQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла проблема с консолью mysql. Когда я добавляю данные в виде русских букв в таблицу через консоль, то вместо них вводятся непонятные иероглифы, но при запросе выводятся уже другие иероглифы.. Уже два дня не могу решить эту проблему, перерыл весь интернет, все попробовал, менял настройки в конфиге my.ini, безрезультатно. Сам использую денвер

Comment: консоль в какой ОС?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: у виндовской консоли кодировка cp866. Лучше поставить какое-нить gui приложение для mysql. Или попробовать первым запросом сделать SET CHARACTER SET 'cp866'; SET NAMES 'cp866'

Comment: или перевести консоль винды в утф. chcp 65001, но это может сработать криво

Comment: Благодарю, помог запрос SET NAMES cp866

Answer (score 1):

Возможно кодировка соединения с базой у приложения отличается от той в которой представлены данные.

Сам использую такой код (php)

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if ($conn -> connect_error) {
    //die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    die("Ошибка подключения к MySQL");
}
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

Comment: С php выводом проблем нет, проблема в том, что консоль почему то тупит. Просто пока я изучаю чисто mysql и тренируюсь в запросах в самой консоле, понимаю что нужно изменить настройки в конфиге, только не понятно какие кодировки нужно проставить.. также пробовал set name utf8 и cp1251, но проблема остается